# Is it possible to switch from CommandText to a Stored Procedure in the same C# method

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use a stored procedure after calling a database with `command.CommandText` within the same method? For example, I want to call a stored procedure after the code snippet below, but I'm unsure how to implement that in my code.

Example:

```
var command = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT id FROM blah_tbl...",
        Connection = conn
    };

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            user.Id = (int) reader["id"];
        }
}

// Stored procedure would be called next
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? It works. Post what you tried and what your problems were and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Why not just make a new command?

Comment: While you probably *could* pull it off - what's the benefit? Why not just create a `SqlCommand` for calling the stored procedure? No harm in that....

Comment: If you're looking to obfuscate your code, then sure, reuse the variable.  But in C#, variables actually do grow on trees, so it's OK to create new ones.  It's much better to create new ones, in fact, because you'll reduce the mental overhead required to read your code, and your code will be more refactorable.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. I'll start declaring a new command. That all being said, not sure why I got downvoted, seemed a pretty straight forward question that sparked a conversation on the pros and cons of the different ways of doing this.

Comment: I think the same as Rex_C said - it wasn't a question which deserves DownVote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void ExecuteTwoCommands ()
{
    var command = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT id FROM blah_tbl...",
        Connection = conn
    };
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
    {
        user.Id = (int) reader["id"];
    }

    // here You need to use Your stored procedure
    command.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // do smoething with new command for exaple:
    command.ExecuteNonQuery;
}
```

EDIT

As few people said in comments it is better(safer for sure, maybe a bit less performance) to create new command instead of using the same again, so Your code would look like this:

```
private void ExecuteTwoCommands ()
{
    var command = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "SELECT id FROM blah_tbl...",
        Connection = conn
    };
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
    {
        user.Id = (int) reader["id"];
    }

    SqlCommand newCommand = new SqlCommand();
    newCommand.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";
    newCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // do smoething with new command for exaple:
    newCommand.ExecuteNonQuery;
}
```

Comment: Just waiting for the time to elapse to accept this answer. I found this same pattern on an IBM documentation site just now. Its legit.

Comment: Yes it works I did in may times. Just remember that if u used parameters in your first command You also need to call command.Parameters.Clear(); before second exec

Comment: I've done it plenty in my own coding practices. Reusing the same command is fine, as long as you remember about any parameters you added and clear them before the next usage.

Comment: @MajkeloDev Is there any good reason to do this? Is there something undesirable about creating a fresh new `SqlCommand`?

Comment: No there is nothing undesirable about creating new command. I just don't like declaring too many variables. For example if i Have a method which I know it will execute 2 commands(not async ofc) i'm doing this like above(usually). TBH Creating new command is a better aproach because You Don't need to remember to clear or dispose something.

Comment: If I would have to suggest the correct approach for some programmer i would deffinetely say "Create new comand for second execution, it's more readable and got less mistake chance"